# How to tell typescript the required type of a keyof

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How do I let the following code know that `u` is a string?

I am currently getting

> `Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

```
interface MyDef   {
    a: "a",
}

export class Router<t>{

    public generate<u extends keyof t>(path: u) {
        this.test(path)
    }

    public test(s: string) {
        console.log(s);
    }

}

const x = new Router<MyDef>();
// "a" is defined in MyDef - should work
x.generate("a");

// should not compile
x.generate("not-in-mydef");
```

Things I have tried

```
interface RouteSet {
    [k: string]: string;
}
// …

export class Router<t extends RouteSet>{
```

```
export class Router<t extends Record<string,string>>{
```

```
export class Router<t extends {[key: string]: string}>{
```

I can't seem to find a way to let TypeScript know I only ever want `u` to be a string.

I can `this.test(path as any as string)` to quiet the compiler, but that's far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys of a type can be strings, numbers or symbols.
You have 2 options:

**Option 1: Take any key on `test` function**

```ts
class Router<T>{

    public generate(path: keyof T) {
        this.test(path)
    }

    public test(s: keyof T) {
        console.log(s);
    }

}
```

**Option 2: restrict allowed keys to strings**

```
class Router1<T>{

    public generate(path: keyof T & string) {
        this.test(path)
    }

    public test(s: string) {
        console.log(s);
    }

}
```

Note: the generic type is not necessary - I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

If you intersect `keyof t` with `string`, you'll get only the keys of `t` that are strings:

```
class Router<t> {
    public generate<u extends keyof t & string>(path: u) {
        this.test(path)
    }

    public test(s: string) {
        console.log(s);
    }
}
```

See some examples in the playground below:

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m36ZkN)

Comment: Just curious - what's wrong with just casting the type explicitly to string? Like `this.test(path as string)`

Comment: @kinduser You'll still be able to pass numbers and symbols to `generate`. OP has said that they only want to be able to pass strings to `generate`. A type assertion would quiet the compiler but it would not prevent numbers and symbols from being passed.